# How to create Time Zone selection like Settings app in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, timezone

I am trying to achieve a selection table view like the one in the Settings app for selecting time zone in an iOS app, where the time zones are displayed with a nicely formatted City and Country name.

From the documentation, the `+ (NSArray *)knownTimeZoneNames` method returns all the "ID"s of the time zones, in alphabetical order but not in "time" order, and those names are quite ugly to read such as `America/New_York`. 
All the other methods in `NSTimeZone` return the localized names such as “Central Standard Time” for Central Time. However those names means nothing for most of the users, as they are used to reason in terms of "cities" instead than in terms of "time zones" (especially in Europe).

Is there a way to achieve the same representation as the one in Settings app using NSTimeZone own methods, or should I build a database of time zones and cities myself?

[image: Settings App time zones example]

Comment: I believe you will find the answer [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/179468-selecting-time-zone-nstimezone.html).

Comment: All right, thanks! So there's some magic going on behind the scenes there...

Comment: Looks like it.  I didn't post as an answer, since it is just a link and I'm not experienced enough with iOS or ObjectiveC to elaborate.  If you find a solution, please post it here as an answer to your own question.  Thanks.

Comment: I know it might be a late answer, but just in case someone else stumbles on it like I did the other day. I just open sourced a library that does exactly this. It is available as a CocoaPod and you can find it here: [https://github.com/gligorkot/TimeZonePicker](https://github.com/gligorkot/TimeZonePicker)